# ¿Está bien organizado el código relacionado a "fetch"?

Tags: javascript, php, phpmyadmin

Estoy tratando de hacer un login utilizando el API fetch, en la que obtengo la data del formulario del login y eso lo paso en el `body` de este método.

en javascript tengo lo siguiente:

```
 const frm_login = document.getElementById('login_form');
frm_login.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (camposLogin.usuario && camposLogin.passw) {
        var formdataL = new FormData(frm_login);
        fetch('usuario.php', {
            method: 'POST',
            body: formdataL
        })
        .then(res => res.json())
            .then(dataU => {
            console.log(dataU);
        )};
    } else {
        document.getElementById('formulario__mensaje-Login').classList.add('claseVisible');
        setTimeout(() => {
            document.getElementById('formulario__mensaje-Login').classList.remove('claseVisible');
            }, 4000);
    }
}
```

en el php lo tengo estructurado en una clase donde hago una función la cual va a ser llamada por otro archivo con extension php para hacer la consulta y es allí donde llegan las variables que se obtienen del formulario.

clase Usuario:

```
<?php
    require "connection/Connection.php";
    class Usuario {
        public function logIn($login_usuario, $login_passw) {
            $db = new Connection();
            $query = "SELECT codigo, nom_usu, cod_tipo_usu FROM usuario WHERE nom_usu = '$login_usuario' AND pass_usu = '$login_passw'";
            $resultado = $db->query($query);
            $datosU = [];
            if ($resultado->nums_rows) {
                $row = $resultado->fetch_assoc();
                while($row = $resultado->fetch_assoc()) {
                    $datosU[] = [
                        'codigoUsu' => $row['codigo'],
                        'nomUsu' => $row['nom_usu'],
                        'tipoUsu' => $row['cod_tipo_usu']
                    ];
                }
            }
            return $datosU;
        }
    }
?>
```

```
<?php
   require "models/Usuario.php";
   $usuario = [];
   if (isset($_POST['login_usuario']) && isset($_POST['login_passw'])) {
      $login_usuario = $_POST['login_usuario'];
      $login_pass = $_POST['login_passw'];
      
      $tabla_usuario = new Usuario();
      $usuario = $tabla_usuario->logIn($login_usuario, $login_passw);
   }
   echo json_encode(['dataUsu' => $usuario]);
?>
```

Tengo entendido que por lo que se nota en las variables, no debo grabar las contraseñas de manera textual pero al ser una práctica lo he dejado de esa forma ya que luego procederé al mejoramiento relacionado a esto de las contraseñas; **en relevancia al código hay algún error?** ya que lo ejecuté y lo trate de ver en consola pero lo que obtuve es que `dataUsu se encuentra vacio`

Comment: Sobra el `while()` porque deberías obtener solo un resultado y, aparte, con `$row = $resultado->fetch_assoc();` avanzas el apuntador de resultados y en el ciclo ya no lee la fila. Prueba primero comentando esa línea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Los métodos `fetch_` **mueven el puntero a la siguiente fila de resultados cada vez que los aplicas**. Por tanto, lo que está ocurriendo ahora en tu código es lo siguiente:

```
# Aquí $row tiene los datos de la primera fila de resultados
$row = $resultado->fetch_assoc(); 

# Aquí empezarías a leer los datos 
# A PARTIR DE LA SEGUNDA FILA SI LA HUBIERA
# dado que más arriba ya colocaste el puntero en la 1ª fila
# Si no hay más filas, ya aquí $row no tendrá nada
# que es lo que está ocurriendo en tu código
while($row = $resultado->fetch_assoc()) {
```

Entonces, si esperas una sola fila, puedes aplicar `fetch_` sin ningún bucle, pues los bucles se usan cuando esperas más de una fila, precisamente para ir moviendo el puntero **mientras haya filas**.

Aparte de eso, estás haciendo dentro del `while` lo mismo que hace `fetch_assoc`, que es devolverte los datos en forma de **array asociativo**, no tienes por tanto que hacer esto:

```
                $datosU[] = [
                    'codigoUsu' => $row['codigo'],
                    'nomUsu' => $row['nom_usu'],
                    'tipoUsu' => $row['cod_tipo_usu']
                ];
```

Aquí habría que preguntarte, ¿si te convenían estos nombres: `codigoUsu`, `nomUsu` y `tipoUsu`, por qué no nombraste tus columnas así en la tabla? Bueno, bueno, no es tan grave. Lo puedes resolver mediante *alias* en la consulta SQL como veremos.

Siendo que el código es confuso (no queda claro si esperas más de una fila), te mostraré dos posibles soluciones:

### 1. Si esperas una sola fila

Pon un `LIMIT 1`  a tu consulta y lee directamente aplicando `fetch_`, no necesitas nada más.

```
<?php
    require "connection/Connection.php";
    class Usuario {
        public function logIn($login_usuario, $login_passw) {
            $db = new Connection();
            $query = "SELECT codigo AS codigoUsu, nom_usu AS nomUsu, cod_tipo_usu AS tipoUsu FROM usuario WHERE nom_usu = '$login_usuario' AND pass_usu = '$login_passw' LIMIT 1";
            $resultado = $db->query($query);
            $mData = [];
            if ($resultado->nums_rows) {
                $mData['status']=true;
                /*
                  En la clave 'data' tendrás ya un array asociativo
                  con los datos de la fila completa 
                  */
                $mData['data'] = $resultado->fetch_assoc();
            } else {
              $mData['status']=false;
              $mData['msg']='No se encontraron filas';                         
            }
            return $mData;
        }
    }
?>
```

**NÓTESE** que aquí yo he optado por un estilo organizado, según el cual he puesto en `$mData` una clave `status` que será `true`  cuando se encuentren datos y esos datos estarán en una clave `data`, en cambio, cuando no haya datos, `status` será `false` y habrá una clave `msg` con un mensaje de error. Esto es útil si quieres implementar una política de manejo de errores, algo esencial en un programa que se respete.

Esta práctica deberá extenderse a la otra parte del código donde recibes los datos del POST. Aquí daremos también **coherencia** al código, según lo dicho en el párrafo anterior:

```
<?php
   require "models/Usuario.php";

  /*
    OJO: Si tu PHP es inferior a la versión 7
    debes cambiar esto por algo de este estilo:
    $usr = !empty($_POST['login_usuario']) ? $_POST['login_usuario'] : null
   */
   
   $usr = $_POST['login_usuario'] ?? null;
   $pass = $_POST['login_passw'] ?? null;

   if ($usr && $pass) {      
      $tabla_usuario = new Usuario();
      $response = $tabla_usuario->logIn($usr, $pass);
   } else {
     $response = array ('status'=>false, 'msg'=>'No se postearon datos');
   }
   echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

Ahora, en el cliente, consumes la respuesta de este modo:

```
    .then(res => res.json())
        .then(dataU => {
            /*Verificas status*/
            if (dataU.status) {
                /*Aquí significa que hay datos*/
                console.log(dataU.data);
            } else {
                /*Aquí significa que hubo error*/
                console.log(dataU.msg);
            }
    )};
```

---

### 2. Si esperas varias filas

Quitas el `LIMIT 1`  a tu consulta como es natural, y en este caso sí deberías leer dentro de un `while`.

```
<?php
    require "connection/Connection.php";
    class Usuario {
        public function logIn($login_usuario, $login_passw) {
            $db = new Connection();
            $query = "SELECT codigo AS codigoUsu, nom_usu AS nomUsu, cod_tipo_usu AS tipoUsu FROM usuario WHERE nom_usu = '$login_usuario' AND pass_usu = '$login_passw'";
            $resultado = $db->query($query);
            $mData = [];
            if ($resultado->nums_rows) {
                $mData['status']=true;
                while($row = $resultado->fetch_assoc()) {
                  /*
                    En este caso en la clave 'data' habrá un array 
                    con todas las filas encontradas asociadas con 
                    el nombre de la columna y el valor
                    */
                  $mData['data'][]= $row;
                }
            } else {
              $mData['status']=false;
              $mData['msg']='No se encontraron filas';                         
            }
            return $mData;
        }
    }
?>
```

Todo lo demás es igual, lo único que cambiaría sería la forma de leer la respuesta en caso de que haya datos, pues en este caso `data` será un array con todas las filas encontradas, y deberás tenerlo en cuenta a la hora de usar los datos así estructurados.

---

#### Post-Data

Tus consultas son vulnerables a ataques de *inyección SQL*, considera usar consultas preparadas para prevenir ese grave problema de seguridad.

Comment: Gracias @A. Cedano; estoy utilizando php version 7.3

Comment: en este caso si estoy esperando una sola fila de respuesta por parte de la tabla; envés del ``fetch_assoc()`` puedo utilizar el ``fetch_row()`` ?

Comment: @SantiagoBarreiro es mejor `fetch_assoc()`, ya que el mismo te devuelve los resultados con los nombres de columna, evitando tener que hacerlo a mano, por eso te dije lo de los alias en la instrucción SQL.